# Сериализация объекта IEnumerable с методом Add в Json

Tags: c#, json, serialize

Привет! Я использую библиотеку Newtonsoft.Json для сериализации объектов.
Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что у меня есть объект, который реализует интерфейс `IEnumerable<T>`. И содержит в себе массив объектов, как свойство.

**C#**

```
class TestObject { }
[JsonObject]
class TestObjects : IEnumerable<TestObject> {
    public int TestProperty { get; set; }

    readonly Collection<TestObject> objects;
    public TestObject[] Objects { get { return objects.ToArray(); } }

    public void Add(TestObject testObject) {
        objects.Add(testObject);
    }

    IEnumerator<TestObject> IEnumerable<TestObject>.GetEnumerator() {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}

var testObjects = new TestObjects {
    new TestObject()
};
testObjects.TestProperty = 5;
```

Для моей задачи, при десериализации, необходимо восстановить в свойство `Objects`, все объекты, через метод `Add(TestObject)`.

Как это можно реализовать?